# Add TextView dynamically and getTag()

Tags: android, menu, android-menu

I have one class calls "SplitText" and extends AsyncTask.
There i added a dynamic textview:

```
TextView masterTV = new TextView(mActivity);
tv.setTag("masterTV");

...
masterTV.setText(Activity_Start.chapterContentList.get(0));

LinearLayout sv = (LinearLayout) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
sv.removeAllViews();
sv.addView(masterTV);
```

This works fine.

Now i want to get the text from this TextView from an other class calls Activity_Start which extends Activity..

on there `onOptionsItemSelected()` i have:

```
    case R.id.menu_previous:
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
        TextView tv = (TextView) ll.findViewWithTag("masterTV");
        Log.e("previs", tv.getText().toString());
        return true;
```

But this returns always a `NullPointerException`..

What i do wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I have found an other way to get my TextView:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
TextView tv = (TextView) ll.getChildAt(0);
```

This isn't the exactly way i want but i runs and do what i want.
(Provided your Textview is child no 0)

Comment: this all you doing in one class or in two?

Comment: in two...The first one i do in a class calls "SplitText" and it extends AsyncTask. The other calls "Activity_Start" and extends Activity...

Comment: Did you add more than one of textview?

Comment: and AsyncTask class is inner class of Activity_Start or you call AsyncTask instance in Activity_Start class?

Comment: @AwadKab: No. But it plays no role, or? Because I search for a particular tag...@Sajmon it isn't a inner class. It is in a separate *.java File...

Comment: please post all the code related